# Using JavaScript in Less

Tags: less

```
@root: "/images";
@app-root: `"@{root}".toUpperCase()`;

#form {
    background: url("@{app-root}/back.jpg");
}
```

Running this in [LESS2CSS](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40root%3A%20%5C%22%2Fimages%5C%22%3B%5Cn%40app-root%3A%20%60%5C%22%40%7Broot%7D%5C%22.toUpperCase()%60%3B%5Cn%5Cn%23form%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20background%3A%20url(%5C%22%40%7Bapp-root%7D%2Fback.jpg%5C%22)%3B%2F%2FBecomes%20url(%5C%22%2FIMAGES%2Fback.jpg%5C%22)%5Cn%7D%22%7D) I get error:

> SyntaxError: JavaScript evaluation error: Unexpected string from
>   `""/images"".toUpperCase()` on line 2, column 12:
>
> 1 @root: "/images"; 2 @app-root: `"@{root}".toUpperCase()`; 3

Supposedly all I need to run JS in LESS is a set of backticks.  So, why does this fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the double quotes, and you are good to go:

```
@app-root: `@{root}.toUpperCase()`;
```

[check here](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40root%3A%20%5C%22%2Fimages%5C%22%3B%5Cn%40app-root%3A%20%60%40%7Broot%7D.toUpperCase()%60%3B%5Cn%5Cn%23form%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20background%3A%20url(%5C%22%40%7Bapp-root%7D%2Fback.jpg%5C%22)%3B%2F%2FBecomes%20url(%5C%22%2FIMAGES%2Fback.jpg%5C%22)%5Cn%7D%22%7D)